# How to generate AST(abstract syntax tree) for Python source code using antlr

Tags: python, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

Grammar for python is given on antlr site  but on using it to generate AST its giving error. I am using same procedure as for java grammar which generated AST .

**Errors:**

```
> C:\testpython>java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Python.g
```

> error(10):  internal error:  : java.lang.Error: Error parsing
>   Python.g: 'class' not expected 'grammar'
>   org.antlr.tool.GrammarSpelunker.match(GrammarSpelunker.java:74)
>   org.antlr.tool.GrammarSpelunker.grammarHeader(GrammarSpelunker.java:112)
>   org.antlr.tool.GrammarSpelunker.parse(GrammarSpelunker.java:84)
>   org.antlr.Tool.sortGrammarFiles(Tool.java:552)
>   org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:408)
>   org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:91) error(100): Python.g:56:1: syntax
>   error: antlr: Python.g:56:1: unexpected token: class error(8):  file
>   Python.g contains grammar PythonParser; names must be identical
>   error(100): Python.g:56:20: syntax error: antlr: Python.g:56:20:
>   expecting SEMI, found 'extends' error(100):  syntax error: invalid
>   char literal: '\014' error(150):  grammar file Python.g has no rules
>   error(100): Python.g:0:0: syntax error: assign.types: :0:0:
>   unexpected end of subtree error(100): Python.g:0:0: syntax error:
>   define: :0:0: unexpected end of subtree

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to generate a parser with ANTLR v3 using a grammar that is written for ANTLR v2. Either find a grammar for v3, or keep the grammar and use ANTLR v2: http://www.antlr2.org/download.html

A grammar that starts like this is targeted for v2:

```
class FooParser extends Parser;
```

and this for v3:

```
grammar FooParser;
```